# Add or update firewall rule

Tags: windows-10, networking, command-line, powershell

I'm using the following command in a powershell script to add a firewall rule to open port 80 for a webserver.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "RemoteData Open Port 80 in" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
```

This however always adds a rule, which causes me to create subsequent rules when i run the script again. I do not want this, I want 1 rule even when executing my script multiple times.

[image]

I also tried to use `set new` rather than `add` but that requires the rule to already be present - it does not add a new rule if no such rule can be found:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set new rule name= "RemoteData Open Port 80 in" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
```

[image]

Powershell script i'm using is nothing interesting:

```
function New-FirewallRule
{
    # NOTE add creates a new rule each time
    Write-Host Creating new firewall rule '"RemoteData Open Port 80 in"'
    & netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name= "RemoteData Open Port 80 in" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
   
    # Below is uncommented and can be uncommented when needed.
    # Write-Host Creating new firewall rule '"RemoteData Open Port 80 out"'
    # & netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "RemoteData Open Port 80 out" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
}

function Run-Main {
    
    Run-PreFlightCheck
    
    New-FirewallRule
}
```

Comment: I don't really have experience managing Windows Firewall with command line tools, but PowerShells `Get/Set/New/-NetFirewallRule` look way more promising than their Batch counterparts. run `get-command *NetFirewallRule*` or even `get-command -m NetSecurity`

Comment: @SimonS Hiya. Hm.. you're right, however the current solution seems to work as it should. Interesting for future readers however. I remember at some point also taking a  very brief look at the powershell options but i wrote them off for some reason, likely because again this was quicker and more familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this snippet in your PowerShell script to check if the rule
already exists:

```
if (netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="RemoteData Open Port 80 in" -contains "No rules match the specified criteria.")
{
  netsh advfirewall firewall set new rule name= "RemoteData Open Port 80 in" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
}
```

Comment: I'm amazed there is no option to add or update the service or something. I'll try this now.

Answer (score 2):

You could first check if the firewall rule already exists, and create it only if it doesn't.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule "RemoteData Open Port 80 in"
```

If it does not exist, you will get

```
No rules match the specified criteria.
```

If it does, it returns the rule's properties.

Comment: Welcome to SU. I suggest that checking the existing answers before answering would help avoid awkward situations.

Comment: @harrymc I was already writing my answer when you posted yours. The page didn't update so I didn't realize.

Comment: When you see an informative message that an answer was posted, it's prudent to click to see the new answer - as somebody might just have been faster.

Comment: Not shown in mobile.

Comment: Unfortunate. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from harrymc worked. I've opted to delete the rule beforehand, to be homogenous with another part of the script. Here's the adapted code for that:

```
function New-FirewallRule
{
    # NOTE add creates a new rule each time
    Write-Host Creating new firewall rule $FireWallRuleName

    if ((& netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name= `"$FireWallRuleName`") -notcontains "No rules match the specified criteria.")
    {
        Write-Host $FireWallRuleName already exists and will be deleted prior to starting
        Write-Host (& netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name= `"$FireWallRuleName`")
    }

    Write-Host (& netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "RemoteData Open Port 80 in" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80)
   
    # Below is uncommented and can be uncommented when needed.
    # Write-Host Creating new firewall rule '"RemoteData Open Port 80 out"'
    # & netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name= "RemoteData Open Port 80 out" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
}
```

Do note that if you have multiple rules with the same name, this will delete all of them. I consider this a feature.